# flutter how to change submit button color when textformfield is not empty?

Tags: flutter

i would like to change the  color of my submit button when the user starts to edit the textformfield, here is what i have tried to do :

```
          final _text = TextEditingController();
```

the textformfield where my controller is implemented

```
          TextFormField(
                  controller: _text,
```

and finally my submit button

```
            (_text.text.isNotEmpty) ?
          new RaisedButton(
            color: mmpataColorBlue,
            child: new Text(
              "Valider",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ),
            onPressed: () async {
              await createOrder(vm);
            },
          ) 
          : 
           new RaisedButton(
             color: Colors.grey,
            child: new Text(
              "Valider",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ),
            onPressed: () async {
              await createOrder(vm);
            },
          )
```

and i got this error while running the code :  **Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/material/text_form_field.dart': Failed assertion: line 176
pos 15: 'initialValue == null || controller == null': is not true.**

Answer (score 0):

from the message error, i think you did set up an initialvalue for the textforifield, this is not possible since you have a controller, instead use :

```
 _text.text = 'your initial value';
```

Answer (score 0):

The way this will work is by adding a `listener` to the controller. Every time the controller value changes, it will trigger the function on the listener (which in this case calls `setState`). The `RaisedButton` will then check is the controller value is empty and proceed to display the corresponding color.

```
class TestPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return TestPageState();
  }
}

class TestPageState extends State<TestPage> {
  TextEditingController _myController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _myController.text = '<initial value>';
    _myController.addListener(() {
      setState(() {}); // setState every time text changes
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _myController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(
              height: 32.0,
              width: 200.0,
              child: TextFormField(
                controller: _myController,
              ),
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                print('pressed');
              },
              color: (_myController.text.isEmpty) ? Colors.blue : Colors.green,
              child: Text('test'),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: i tried it but the same error appears, is there any code i have to insert the setState method?

Comment: As mentioned by Rechem, you have to remove your initial value, did you do so?

Comment: yes i removed it, you mean the value must be like this :  _text.text= ' '  ?

Comment: Just try adapting ur code onto the structure tht my code shows. the _text.text line should be in ur init state and u need to use stateful widget

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use validator for this. You could use a variable to define the color of the button and use setState in the validator to change it.